# Gdal_calc.py and numpy conditional

Tags: raster, gdal, numpy

I want to use gdal_calc.py to reclassify a raster using numpy's conditional statements, but I am running into an error message. It appears that gdal_calc.py cannot access the numpy conditional functions. Does anyone know how to link numpy in the gdal_calc.py system call?

```
system('"C:\\Miniconda2\\python.exe" "C:\\Miniconda2\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\scripts\\gdal_calc.py" --co="COMPRESS=LZW" -A D:/xx.tif --outfile=D:/yy.tif --calc="A*logical_or(A<=0)" --NoDataValue=0')
```

Here is the error message:

```
0 .. evaluation of calculation A*logical_or(A>=1) failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Miniconda2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\scripts\gdal_calc.py", line 326, 
in <module>
main()
File "C:\Miniconda2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\scripts\gdal_calc.py", line 323, 
in main
doit(opts, args)
File "C:\Miniconda2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\scripts\gdal_calc.py", line 272, 
in doit
myResult = eval(opts.calc)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'logical_or' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the "logical_or" in you calc formula. For example, the following code removes pixels with a value below 10:

```
gdal_calc.py --format=KEA -A InputImage.kea --calc=A*(A>=10) --NoDataValue=0 --outfile=OutputImage.kea
```

If you intend to reclassify an image using several rules, I'd suggest using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) statements. Here is an example in Python:

```
import numpy
from osgeo import gdal

InputImage = 'ImageName'
OutputImage = 'OutImageName'

Image = gdal.Open(InputImage, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
Driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(Image.GetDriver().ShortName)
X_Size = Image.RasterXSize
Y_Size = Image.RasterYSize
Projection = Image.GetProjectionRef()
GeoTransform = Image.GetGeoTransform()

# Read the first band as a numpy array
Band1 = Image.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()

# Create a new array of the same shape and fill with zeros
NewClass = numpy.zeros_like(Band1).astype('uint8')

# Reclassify using numpy.where
NewClass = numpy.where(((Band1 > 0) & (Band1 < 10)), 1, NewClass) # Reclassify as 1
NewClass = numpy.where(((Band1 >= 10) & (Band1 < 20)), 2, NewClass) # Reclassify as 2
NewClass = numpy.where(((NewClass == 0) & (Band1 >= 20)), 3, NewClass) # Reclassify as 3
del Band1

# Export the new classification to an image:
OutImage = Driver.Create(OutputImage, X_Size, Y_Size, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)
OutImage.SetProjection(Projection)
OutImage.SetGeoTransform(GeoTransform)
OutBand = OutImage.GetRasterBand(1)
OutBand.SetNoDataValue(0)
OutBand.WriteArray(NewClass)
OutImage = None
del NewClass
print("Done.")
```

By using numpy.where, you can create more sophisticated classification rules than you would otherwise be able to using gdal_calc.py.